# Youtube api v3 get active streams for channels list

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying get the currently active live streams for list of channels. I know, that there is [search/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method, but it costs 100 units of api quota and only applicable for one channel per request. It's impossible to update stream avaibility frequently for large number of channels with total quota of 1M api units per day.

So, is there any other way, i can get active streams for channel or list of channels, avoiding "heavy" search method?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [`Live Streaming API - LiveStreams:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started), LiveStreams:list returns a list of video streams that match the API request parameters.

**HTTP request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams
```

Note that in every request needs authorizing access to provate user data. You need to implement [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication).

Include `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter, this parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and manage many different YouTube channels. It allows content owners to authenticate once and get access to all their video and channel data, without having to provide authentication credentials for each individual channel.

**HTTP response:**

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#liveStreamListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    liveStream Resource
  ]
}
```

Here's a sample code snippet how to request liveStream resources:

```
 // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-liststreams-sample")
                    .build();
        // Create a request to list liveStream resources.
        YouTube.LiveStreams.List livestreamRequest = youtube.liveStreams().list("id,snippet");

        // Modify results to only return the user's streams.
        livestreamRequest.setMine(true);

        // Execute the API request and return the list of streams.
        LiveStreamListResponse returnedListResponse = livestreamRequest.execute();
        List<LiveStream> returnedList = returnedListResponse.getItems();

        // Print information from the API response.
        System.out.println("\n================== Returned Streams ==================\n");
        for (LiveStream stream : returnedList) {
            System.out.println("  - Id: " + stream.getId());
            System.out.println("  - Title: " + stream.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println("  - Description: " + stream.getSnippet().getDescription());
            System.out.println("  - Published At: " + stream.getSnippet().getPublishedAt());
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
```

Comment: I think this api method is for cases, when stream is owned by account that sends request. In my case, i'm just trying to detect when some of my "subscribtions" are streaming new live video.